# Trying to call setState of main app.js throws component is not mounted warning

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've had major issues the last few days getting state information into the custom `contentComponent` of my `createDrawerNavigator`. I've decided to make a few pieces of content global such as user ID using the state of app.js and just passing the state as screenProps to the router like so.

App.js

```
state = {
    score:0,
    rank:0,
}
setScore = (value) => this.setState({score:value});
setRank = (value) => this.setState({rank:value});

render() {
  const globalProps={
      state:this.state,
      setScore:this.setScore,
      setRank:this.setRank
  }

let RootNav = createRootNavigator();
return (
    <RootNav screenProps={globalProps}></RootNav>
);
```

Router.js

```
contentComponent: ({ navigation, screenProps}) => (
  <DrawerContent navigation={navigation} screenProps={screenProps}/>
),
```

Child.js

```
this.props.screenProps.setScore(5);
```

I'm able to access the data, but when I call to `setState` from the child I get the warning telling me that app.js is unmounted. My understanding was that app.js was always mounted and running because it contains your entire app? if anyone has a solution for this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by moving `let RootNav = createRootNavigator()` outside the class declaration

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting this error because you're setting your state in the render method of your component. You would need to move it up into a lifecycle method like componentDidMount(). See the example below of your refactored code.

```
state = {
  score:0,
  rank:0,
}
setScore = (value) => this.setState({score:value});
setRank = (value) => this.setState({rank:value});

componentDidMount(){
   const globalProps={
      state:this.state,
      setScore:this.setScore,
      setRank:this.setRank
  }
}

render() {

 let RootNav = createRootNavigator();
 return (
   <RootNav screenProps={globalProps}></RootNav>
);
```

The componentDidMount() runs everytime the component is called or data/state changes. I think setting your state in the render() is not good practice. i havent actually tested this code but if it doesnt work you could try sending more code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already fixed the issue so I won't be using this method.